# How can I connect to and query a CRM (Dynamics 365) database from a netcoreapp1.0?

Tags: asp.net-core, dynamics-crm, asp.net-core-webapi

I've been looking for solutions on how to connect to CRM/Dynamics 365 but it seems like the options are fairly limited in .Net Core. I've tried the standard OAuth message, but because AcquireToken is obselete in .Net core, I get lost trying to figure out the `AcquireTokenAsync` method. I've also tried using the `Xrm` package but with a lack of documentation I find myself stuck. What's the best way to handle this issue?

Comment: David Yack's WebAPI helper seems to have a .NET Core version, which may help: https://github.com/davidyack/Xrm.Tools.CRMWebAPI/tree/master/dotnet/Xrm.Tools.WebAPI.Core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it once, but it's not really a common thing to do right now.

First you need to install **Microsoft Adal Libraries** but not Version 3+. (Take 2.28 for example).

Than you can download the latest `Microsoft.CrmSdk.Core` Packages from Nuget.

There is a [guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn688177.aspx) from microsoft how to connect using those latest libraries.

Comment: When I try to install the CrmSdk.Coreassemblies NuGet package I get this: Package Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies 8.2.0.2 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0

Comment: there is already an issue open for this one: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/604